# Regex to match markdown headings and text nested under specific heading

Tags: javascript, regex, obsidian

I am using [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md) (which uses ECMAScript) with the [Obsidian_to_Anki](https://github.com/Pseudonium/Obsidian_to_Anki)-Plugin and I have this page structure:

```markdown
# Heading 1 ⤵
## Heading 1.1
Text of Heading 1.1
Text can span over multiple lines
Even more text
## Heading 1.2 
Text of Heading 1.2
# Heading 2
## Heading 2.1
Text of Heading 2.1
## Heading 2.2
Text of Heading 2.2
# Heading 3 ⤵
## Heading 3.1
Text of Heading 3.1
## Heading 3.2
Text of Heading 3.2
# Heading 4
```

I need a RegExp that matches all `## Headings` and `Text of Headings` that are nested under `# Heading ⤵`. The `⤵` should function as a kind of switch here. All `## Headings` and `Text of headings` should be matched with capturing groups. So Content nested under `# Heading` without the `⤵` should not be matched. Hence the matched text should be:

```markdown
## Heading 1.1
Text of Heading 1.1
More text
Even more text
## Heading 1.2
Text of Heading 1.2
## Heading 3.1
Text of Heading 3.1
## Heading 3.2
Text of Heading 3.2
```

[Here's what I came up with regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gg5tU9/1). My problem is, that this way only the first `## headings and texts` get matched and I can't find a solution.

Comment: Like this? https://regex101.com/r/fBXTJO/1

Comment: Headings and text nested under `# Heading 2` (so a Heading without '⤵') is also beeing matched like this. Only content after after `# Heading ⤵` until the next `# Heading` or `# Heading ⤵`should be matched

Comment: Then perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/r7CdRM/1

Comment: That looks promising! Only problem was, that further nested headings like `### Heading` weren't matched (see [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/y23u7h/1)). [This Regex](https://regex101.com/r/4icjG4/1) seems to work perfectly for me, thank you very much! Could you maybe explain the RegExp than in your answer? I don't perfectly understand what's going on

Comment: I posted the pattern with a slight modification not matching `# ` or `## `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use:

```
(?<=^# .*⤵(?:\n(?!# ).*)*)\n(^## .*)\n(?!^##? )(.*(?:\n(?!^##? ).*)*)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert that to the left is

  - `^# .*⤵` Match `#`  and the rest of the line ending on `⤵`
  - `(?:\n(?!# ).*)*` Optionally match all lines that do not start with 1+ `#` chars and a space
  - `\n` Match a newline
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `(^## .*)` Capture **group 1**, match `##`  followed by the rest of the line
- `\n` Match a newline
- `(?!^##? )` Negative lookahead, assert that the line does not start with # or ## and a space
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `.*` Match the whole line
  - `(?:\n(?!^##? ).*)*` Optionally match all lines that do not start with # or ## and a space
- `)` Close group 2

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/51voNG/1)

Comment: I ran into a little problem after testing the RegExp with Obsidian. The Obsidian_to_Anki plugin has an automatic context function (which I need). The context function tells you, were the Heading is in the text. So e.g. for `Heading 1.1` it should be `Heading 1 > Heading 1.1`, with your RegExp it changed to only `Heading 1`. For `Heading 1.2` it changed to `Heading 1 > Heading 1.1`. So it is basically shifted up wrongly by one position. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: @lukaskupfing I really don't know why that happens. What happens if you introduce another capture group for the first `# Heading 1` like https://regex101.com/r/X6ufDy/1

Comment: After some testing, I found that the problem is the second `\n`. Removing that solved the problem, and the rest is still working: https://regex101.com/r/gffV2P/1

Comment: @lukaskupfing Good to hear that it is working!