# How to select markdown text under heading containing a keyword with regexp?

Tags: regex, parsing, markdown

I am trying to match content under a specific heading level when title contains a `[[Wikilink]]` keyword (use case: Obsidian)

I want it to match lower level headings.

Example `[[Wikilink]]` is in an H2, then match all below until h2 or higher or end of file

Difficulty: `[[Wikilink]]` H-level is unknown. The regex should be able to parse multiple inconsistent files where `[[Wikilink]]` could be H1, H2, H3, etc.

My current regex that fails when it encounters any heading:

```
(^#+ )[^\[]*?\[\[Wikilink]\][^\n]*?\n([\S\s]*?)(?1)
```

Sandbox: https://regex101.com/r/bLdifP/1

Somehow related to this question on SO: [Regex to match markdown headings and text nested under specific heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202003/regex-to-match-markdown-headings-and-text-nested-under-specific-heading)

Comment: [Is it better](https://regex101.com/r/bLdifP/2)?

Comment: Almost thanks for your contribution. It still has to match the lower level headings (e.g. content from below `## Some title 1 [[Wikilink]]` to before `## Other title 2`.

Comment: So, you need overlapping matches? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/bLdifP/3).

Comment: I am unsure about the exact meaning of overlapping match, but to put my objective in other words: I want to extract all the content below every heading (including sub-headings) that contain `[[Wikilink]]`. I don't know whether it is H1, H2, or Hx. Several MD headings might have the keyword (multiple matches, like in example text). With your last example, it seems that the matching below `## Some title 1 [[Wikilink]]` doesn't go all the way down to before this other same level heading `## Other title 2`. Maybe I messed with the different groups.

Comment: Here are the expected matches: https://pastebin.com/PZFtCyZY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following [regex](https://regex101.com/r/24HXkY/3).

```
^(#+) .*\[\[Wikilink\]\].*$(?=([\S\s]*?)(?:^(?!\1#+)#+ |\z))
```

Regex in action: https://regex101.com/r/bLdifP/4

The regex can be broken down as follows.

```
^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------
(                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the most
                           amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                         ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------
.*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Wikilink                 'Wikilink'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
\]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
.*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                         (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
$                        before an optional \n, and the end of a
                         "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------
(?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    [\S\s]*?                 any character of: non-whitespace (all
                             but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " "),
                             whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                             (0 or more times (matching the least
                             amount possible)).
                             Match any character, including line
                             breaks.
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture, equivalent 
                           to "(?>":
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of a "line"
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      \1                       what was matched by capture \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------
      #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the
                               most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    #+                       '#' (1 or more times (matching the
                             most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------
                             ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------
    \z                       the end of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: Thank you Andrei, this is working as expected! Demo here: https://regex101.com/r/bLdifP/4

Comment: May I ask you how did you generate the text based broken down explanation, please?

Comment: @NicolasLIENART, yes, sure. To generate an explanation i use  the following site https://myregextester.com.